# Facebook Like Button for each image

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am trying to create an image gallery using asp.net, now I have to add a facebook *like* button for each images in the image gallery. I used the following code to display images in image gallery:

```
<a href='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," +
  Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("imgdata")) %>' class="swipebox"  title="Image Title">
<img src='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," +
  Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("imgdata")) %>'
  width="300px" height="250px" alt=""  />
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. What is not working?

Comment: i have to use fb like button for each images in the image gallery

Comment: You need an individual URL for each image. If you don’t want to use the actual image URL (because that might look not so good when a post about someone liking it is shown on Facebook), then you need to set up an individual HTML document for each image, that contains the relevant OG meta data.